# string Regex using lex

Tags: regex, lex

I'm trying to make a Regex for a string which it's rules are:

> *A String starts with `"` and ends in a `"`. It can't be split to two lines. The character `"` can be in the string iff it has an escaped
>   character before `\`.*

What I did was:

**sstr  (\"[^\"\n|\r\n]*\")**

For example: given this line: `"block inside \"function\""`
I should get that my string is : `block inside \"function\"`

But when there is this line : `"block inside "function\""`

I'm getting that my string is `block inside "function\"` which is wrong..

**The answer is in the comments. If the owner of it decides to post it as an answer I'll pin it.**

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and _clearly_ show us several examples of sample input and the output you are trying to match.

Comment: Why are you listing `\n` twice in your character class? And why is `|` not allowed in your strings?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added one example, i'll add more in a minute

Comment: @melpomene /r/n for linux users, and \n for windows. Isn't `|` for the operation or?

Comment: Not inside a character class.

Comment: I was downvoted off by @melpomene (don't even know what that word means), but I was having difficulty because of the possibility of nested quotation marks.  In general, for nested structure, like JSON or your text, it is preferable to use a parser.  I also wonder why you are processing intermediate text with escaped quotes in it.

Comment: I don't see how this involves nesting. The standard regex for quoted strings is something like `"([^\n"\\]|\\[\\"])*"`, but I don't know lex. And OP needs to post a [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene Um....there are quoted terms inside a set of outer quotes.  That's nested content.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My solution is totally wrong it seems! Any other suggestions? where to look for in the internet perhaps?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Where do you see quoted terms inside of outer quotes?

Comment: @Ameerkhan I revived my answer below.  It seems to work, at least in the demo.  Not sure about lex regex flavor though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your answer is using features which [`lex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) does not support.

Comment: Should'nt lex take the longest match it finds? Why in this website regex101 it doesnt?

Comment: @melpomene your answer worked for me.
Just enhance it for lex `\"([^\n\"\\]|\\[\\"])*\"`

Comment: @rici Yes, it is a duplicate! Just found another error and fixed it after you posted this link.
Should I delete this post or what?
The final answer is: `\"([^\r\"\\]|\\[\"\\n])*\"`

Comment: Didn't find that post when I searched for posts about my issue.